# C++ how to overload operator < for complex numbers?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The following code works for comparing two complex numbers in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

class Complex {
private:
    float real; 
    float imag; 
public:
    Complex(float realVal, float imagVal): real(realVal), imag(imagVal){}

    double magnitude()
    {
        return sqrt(real*real)+sqrt(imag*imag);

    }

    friend bool operator<(Complex& c1, Complex& c2)
    {
        if(c1.magnitude() < c2.magnitude())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1(3, 3);
    Complex c2(4, 4);
    cout << (c2 < c1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I can't the `operator<()` function to work with `const` parameters, because of `magnitude()`. Specifically, the following error is thrown: `error: passing ‘const Complex’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`. What's the solution to that problem?

Comment: `operator<` does not modify its operators, pass them as `const` reference and make `magnitude` const too, it doesnt modify `this` as well

Comment: Declare that method as `double magnitude() const`. Also, in the that operator, take references to const, like `friend bool operator<(const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2)`.

Comment: Note that `if (c1.magnitude() < c2.magnitude()) return true; else return false;` is usually written `return c1.magnitude() < c2.magnitude();`.

Comment: The only part of `Complex` that `operator<` uses is `magnitude()`. `magnitude()` is a **public** member, so there is no reason for `operator<` to be a friend. Also, for an object that's small like `Complex`, pass it by value: `bool operator<(Complex c1, Complex c2) { return c1.magnitude() < c2.magnitude(); }`.

Comment: Whoops, `magnitude()` doesn't look right. As written, it returns `std::abs(real) + std::abs(imag)`, but with a much more long-winded calculation. Probably should be `std::sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help, here's the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Complex {
private:
    float real; 
    float imag; 
public:
    Complex(float realVal, float imagVal): real(realVal), imag(imagVal) {}

    double magnitude() const
    {
        return sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);
    }

    friend bool operator<(const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2)
    {
        return c1.magnitude() < c2.magnitude();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1(3, 3);
    Complex c2(4, 4);
    cout << (c2 < c1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also, if I remove `friend` before `bool operator<`, the code doesn't work. The error that gets printed out is:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

main.cpp:29:17: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘Complex’ and ‘Complex’)
```

Comment: If you remove the `friend` you **also** have to move it outside the class. Otherwise it looks like an odd member function.